# Compiling OpenJDK 6 from sources on Windows 7 using Windows SDK v7.1

Tags: windows, java, winsock2

I am trying to compile the OpenJDK 6 from sources on a Windows 7 machine with Windows SDK v7.1.

After some tweaks I reached a point where I really do not know what is the right thing to do.

Here is the file - http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk6/jdk6/jdk/file/tip/src/windows/native/sun/nio/ch/WindowsSelectorImpl.c

The lines 47 and 49:

```
   static int POLLIN   = 1;  // line 47
   static int POLLCONN = 2;
   static int POLLOUT  = 4;  // line 49
```

The problem is that the included file winsock2.h has the following code:

```
#if(_WIN32_WINNT >= 0x0600)

/* Event flag definitions for WSAPoll(). */

#define POLLRDNORM  0x0100
#define POLLRDBAND  0x0200
#define POLLIN      (POLLRDNORM | POLLRDBAND)
#define POLLPRI     0x0400

#define POLLWRNORM  0x0010
#define POLLOUT     (POLLWRNORM)
#define POLLWRBAND  0x0020

#define POLLERR     0x0001
#define POLLHUP     0x0002
#define POLLNVAL    0x0004

typedef struct pollfd {

    SOCKET  fd;
    SHORT   events;
    SHORT   revents;

} WSAPOLLFD, *PWSAPOLLFD, FAR *LPWSAPOLLFD;

#endif // (_WIN32_WINNT >= 0x0600)
```

Notice how winsock2 #defines `POLLIN` and `POLLOUT`, whereas WindowsSelectorImpl.c declares them as consts. Even worse, both give different values:

**OpenJDK:**

```
POLLIN = 1
POLLOUT = 4
```

WinSock2 (Windows SDK v7.1):

```
POLLIN = 0x300
POLLOUT = 0x10
```

Obviously, the OpenJDK code is not supposed to be compiled on Windows 7.

However, I do want to compile it on Windows 7.

One of the options is installing an older Windows SDK. Another is to change the file WindowsSelectorImpl.c, the question is how? My intention is to rename the constants, but I cannot help wondering about WinSock2 #defining constants with exactly the same names, but different values...

Any advices?

**EDIT1**

On second thought, maybe I am better off conditionally using the values from WinSock2? I mean the change in values probably means a change in API.

WinSock2.h defines pollfd like this:

```
typedef struct pollfd {
    SOCKET  fd;
    SHORT   events;
    SHORT   revents;
} WSAPOLLFD, *PWSAPOLLFD, FAR *LPWSAPOLLFD;
```

vs WindowsSelectorImpl.c:

```
typedef struct {
    jint fd;
    jshort events;
} pollfd;
```

The former is being backward compatible with the latter (more or less, alignment aside).

So, there is a chance WinSock2 constants are the right ones for Windows 7, but then what to do with `POLLCONN` ? And how will the code run on Windows 2003 or XP?

**EDIT2**

Things are even worse, because the C implementation has a matching counterpart in java - http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk6/jdk6/jdk/file/tip/src/windows/classes/sun/nio/ch/WindowsSelectorImpl.java, which uses the same constants as the C code.

I do not get it. Does winsock2 on Windows 7 breaks any code written for winsock2 on Windows 2003 SP1?

**EDIT3**

Checked the jdk7u sources ([WindowsSelectorImpl.c](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk7u/jdk7u/jdk/file/tip/src/windows/native/sun/nio/ch/WindowsSelectorImpl.c) and [AbstractPollArrayWrapper.java](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk7u/jdk7u/jdk/file/tip/src/share/classes/sun/nio/ch/AbstractPollArrayWrapper.java)). It uses the rename approach, meaning even though the Windows SDK v7.1 declares POLLIN and POLLOUT with the different values, jdk7 sticks to the implementation of jdk6.

I really do not know what does it mean, but I am not going to be more catholic here than the Pope.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is simple, though annoying - get Visual Studio 2003 and use it to compile OpenJDK. The most difficult part is to get VS2003 itself, all the rest is easy.